# How do you create and view .realm files?

Tags: react-native, realm

For example there are apps for SQLite or PostgreSQL to view the database in a GUI or a CLI. Is it possible to do this with Realm?

If not what is the best approach in creating a .realm file so that I can load it into my React Native application?

Comment: If you are using OSX: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx

Comment: @Jon Thank you! 